# how to bind input value to the formcontrol in angular?

Tags: angular

i have a nested form control(two input box by default but can add more), the values are set from an array of values(loop). These values cannot bind to the form control.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vcs1eCEB9d6bxhONBKZP?p=preview)

Please have a look at my code below,

```
<div formArrayName="dayanddescriptions">
    <div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let dayAndDescription of this.createFormService.formGroup.controls.dayanddescriptions.controls; let i = index" >
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span>Day {{i + 1}}</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="i>0"  
                  (click)="removeDayandDescription(i)">                    
            </span>
        </div>          
        <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
            <!--Day-->
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4" >
                <label for="text">Day</label>
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="day"  value="{{i + 1}}" readonly>                    
            </div>
            <!--Description-->
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                <label>Description</label>
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="description">
            </div>                           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my form value in json,

```
form: { "title": null, "metaDescription": "", "singleImageUploadsImageName": "", "multipleImageUploadsImageName": [], "unDevelopmentGoals": "", "mainEditor": "", "introduction": null, "experiencecategory": "", "dayanddescriptions": [ { "description": "" }, { "description": "" } ], "hashtags": "" }
```

these are the part of its component ,

```
initDayandDescription() {       
        return this.createFormService._formBuilder.group({
            day: ['', Validators.required],
            description: [''],
        });
    }     
    createForm() {
        this.formService.buildForm(this.createFormService._formBuilder.group({
            title: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(20), Validators.maxLength(64)])],
            metaDescription: '',
            singleImageUploadsImageName: '',
            multipleImageUploadsImageName: '',
            unDevelopmentGoals: '',
            mainEditor: '',
            introduction: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(50), Validators.maxLength(124)])],
            experiencecategory: '',
            dayanddescriptions: this.createFormService._formBuilder.array([
                this.initDayandDescription(),
            ]),           
            hashtags: '',           
        }));
    }
```

Comment: so you have default values that you want to insert? Question is a bit unclear, best would be if you could create a plunker :)

Comment: When you type in any input boxes,  these values are immediately reflected in form value.  For  one of the input box,  a value is assigned like below,  <input  type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="day"  value="{{i + 1}}" readonly>..  This value is reflected in the text box but not in the form value

Comment: *When you type in any input boxes, there values are immediately reflected in form value*. Okay so what do you want it to do when you type values?

Comment: But it is not reflected here form: { "title": null, "metaDescription": "", "singleImageUploadsImageName": ""}

Comment: Okay, now I understand :) Could you please add how you are building the form in your component?

Comment: you actually don't type the values,  the values are set through value attribute.  Values are displayed in the input box. But not stored in the form object. When you type it is shown both in the input box and in form object. Here the value is set through the value attribute,  so the value is displayed in the input box but not in the form object.

Comment: Don't use the value attribute, use the formControlName to set the values.

Comment: how can i do this?
here form control name is already set to a child form control name <input  type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="day"  value="{{i + 1}}" readonly>
and in the component as,
this.createFormService._formBuilder.group({
            day: ['', Validators.required],
            description: [''],
        });

Comment: Use `patchValue` or `setValue` to set the default values after you have built your form.

Comment: these values are populated from the for loop. is there any other way to bind the values to the form object

Comment: It's impossible to help unless you create a plunker, so that we can look at the code, since this is very little information to go on ;)

Comment: i do not know how to add this code in plunker let me try

Comment: There is a ready template in Plunker for angular, there, I started one for you :) http://plnkr.co/edit/XvwkIlS4EmVMfvc0iQWk

Comment: Here is the link,
http://plnkr.co/edit/vcs1eCEB9d6bxhONBKZP?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We just need to do a minor change to the code! :)

Instead of using `[value]`, let's use one-way-binding instead, so just replace `[value]` with `[ngModel]`:

```
<input  type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="day" 
     [ngModel]="i + 1"  readonly>
```

Your forked [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gs02hMFBhi4SAu19WZoQ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. I din try that.

Comment: You are welcome, sorry it took a while, I just had trouble understanding what was going on. Seeing all the code cleared it right out. Have a great day and happy coding! :)

Comment: great day and happy coding to you too :)

Comment: Deprecated now https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel